# Haproxy ACL to compare values in the headers

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I use the Haproxy as the SSL termination to identify client side certificate. I want to check the CN value in the client certificate if it matches a header value sent by the client. Is there a way to set ACL if the CN value in the certificate does not match the value in the header?

Something like:

```
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN     %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
acl id_not_match hdr(client-id) -m hdr(X-SSL-Client-CN)
```

Answer (score 3):

A Sample configuration to check CN and allow authentication based on a list:

```
frontend www-https
   ....
   http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
   use_backend www-backend
backend www-backend
   acl allow_users req.fhdr(X-SSL-Client-CN) -m str -f /etc/haproxy/ssl/userslist
   http-request deny if !allow_users
   ....
   server www-1 <ip>:<port> check
   server www-2 <ip>:<port> check
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question; they were trying to check if two header values match whereas this answer checks if one of the headers is in a static list of users

Answer (score 1):

Due to restrictions of HAProxy ACL grammar, you can only compare a sample (e.g. a header value) with literal (e.g. a string).

If you have to do such comparison, you can compare whatever you want using Lua. See [this thread from HAProxy community](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/is-it-possible-to-do-string-match-with-host-header-a-custom-variable/3758).

Answer (score 1):

```
http-request set-var-fmt(txn.client_cn) %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
acl id_not_match req.fhdr(client-id),strcmp(txn.client_cn) eq 0
```

This uses [`set-var-fmt`](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#4.4-set-var) to create a new transaction-scoped (`txn`) variable which I've called `client_cn`, which we then compare against the client-id header with the [`strcmp` filter](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#7.3.1-strcmp).

If you don't need to use a format string, you can just use [`set-var`](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#4.4-set-var):

```
http-request set-var(txn.client_cn) ssl_c_s_dn(cn)
```

And if you're only going to use the variable in request processing you can use the `req` scope (only available during request processing):

```
http-request set-var(req.client_cn) ssl_c_s_dn(cn)
acl id_not_match req.fhdr(client-id),strcmp(req.client_cn) eq 0
```

Note I've used [`req.fhdr`](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.fhdr) instead of [`hdr`](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.9/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.hdr). `hdr` assumes the value is comma-separated like Accept-Language and can lead to unexpected behavior. It returns the last comma-separated value.